# VSTO Outlook: Opening Outlook from a mailto link does not create custom task pane

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, com-interop

I have an VSTO Outlook Addin which shows always an Outlook custom task pane in all windows, explorers and inspectors. This is working perfectly, I mean, custom task pane is always show, except one particular use case, e.g. when you open outlook by clicking in a mailto link in a web page for example. In this case no explorer is open, instead only one knspector window is open, in this case the reply/compose window. So I need to handle when outlook is open through a mailto link and show my custom task pane in the reply/compose window, so which event do i need to handle? It looks like in this case i am not calling the logic to show my custom task pane when there are 0 explorers opened. I want to handle that event , check if numbers of explorers opened are 0 and then in this case show my ctp. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Inspectors.NewInspector` event, it won't fire for the `mailto` links. What you can do, is create a timer (use the Timer object from the `Form` namespace - it fires on the same thread) that checks the `Application.Inspectors` collection periodically and verifies that your task pane has been added to that inspector. You can create an `Inspector` wrapper class that handles `Inspector.Close` to remove itself from the parent list maintained by your code as well as contains a pointer to your task pane. When looping through the Outlook's inspectors collection, you can match OOM's Inspector object to your wrapper by comparing the HWND of an `Inspector` object to that stored by your wrapper. The window handle (`HWND`) can be retrieved using the `IOleWindow` interface - cast the Inspector object to `IOleWindow` and call `IOleWindow.GetWindow`